# zend framework Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, zend-framework

im trying to modify a code, when i submit the form im getting this error "Creating default object from empty value". I make n echo statment in $request->isPost is not echoing. this my code below

```
public function addAction() {


            $report = new Report();
    $request = $this->getRequest ();
    $validateOnly = $request->isXmlHttpRequest ();
    if ($validateOnly)
    $this->setNoRenderer ();

    $userObj = new User ( );
    $userRow = $userObj->createRow();

    $status = ValidationContainer::instance ();
    $userArray = $userRow->toArray ();
    $userArray['acls'] = User::getACLs ( $user_id ); //set acls
    $this->viewAssignEscaped ( 'user', $userArray );

            $locations = Location::getAll();
    $this->viewAssignEscaped('locations', $locations);
            //var_dump($locations); exit;

    if ($request->isPost()) {

            self::fillFromArray ( $userRow, $details );

            $userRow->is_blocked = 0;
            if ($id = $userRow->save ()) {

                  in the provider_code table.
                                    $this->insertPlainPassword($this->getSanParam('password'), $id);

                $status->setStatusMessage ( 'The new user was created.' );
                $this->saveAclCheckboxes ( $id );
            } else {
                $status->setStatusMessage ( 'The user could not be saved.' );
            }

        }
    }


}
```

i have been trying to resolve it for weeks now.
    }

Comment: Did you check That "fill from array" method? Your code contains so much hidden parts. I don't know half of code what is doing. But this error definetly not a part öf zf.

Comment: i just discovered the request is ajax request, $request->isPost is empty. what can i replace that with ?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ the userRow is empty    if ($id = $userRow->save()) {
                    
                }

Comment: request is ajax or not post is post. so $request->isPost must be valid.

Comment: you right, without using ajax its working.